# Métodos bind_result y store_result

Tags: php, pdo

alguien sabe si en PHP 7, utilizando PDO se siguen utilizando los métodos

1. bind_result()
2. store_result()

O si en PDO han sido sustituidos o mejorado estos métodos.

Gracias

Comment: En los dos casos concretos que expones, sería un grave error... quizá una fuente de confusión, pensar a PDO como un sucedáneo de MySQLi o viceversa. Son dos cosas distintas. Yo diría que PDO hace fácil aquello que MySQLi hace difícil obligándote a *marear*  el código para obtener resultados. Un ejemplo típico es la dificultad para obtener resultados sin tener que bindear variables una por una de forma explícita (esa es la función de `bind_result`). Ya sabes, si necesitas 100 columnas, debes bindear 100 variables si no tienes el driver `mysqlnd`. PDO descartó todo eso, haciendo las cosas...

Comment: ... mucho más fáciles. Este es sólo un caso ([esta respuesta puede ayudar a aclarar dudad sobre `bind_result`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18710948/5587982)). En cuanto a `store_result`, también fue superado, con creces, por PDO. A mi juicio, MySQLi es *mediocre* en ese sentido, por el simple hecho de hacer depender ciertas cosas de un drive adicional: si escribes código basándote en eso, tu código no funcionará si algún servidor no tiene ese drive instalado. Es *mediocre*  por eso, y por otras cosas más. MySQLi se quedó corto, a mi juicio.

Comment: Saludos @A.Cedano, y si, creo que tienes razon en lo absoluto, MySQLi es demasiado engorroso para muchas cosas, por eso PDO es y sera 3mil veces mejor. Estupendo comentario, gracias!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Te comento que indepediente de la versión de PHP **store_result()** no pertenece a PDO si no a mysqli()

Como notas en la línea siguiente su equivalente sería hacer uso de execute()

```
$sentencia = $conexion->prepare("SELECT * FROM productos");
$sentencia->execute();
```

Ahora para el caso de **bind_result()** también pertenece a mysqli, si lo que buscas es su equivalente es bindParam y lo usas del modo siguiente

```
$id = 1;

$sentencia = $conexion->prepare("SELECT * FROM productos WHERE id = :id");
$sentencia->bindParam("id", $id, PDO::PARAM_INT);
$sentencia->execute();
```

Como notas en el ejemplo anterior tengo una variable llamada id que se la paso con el marcador de doble dos puntos a la sentencia y después justo antes de ejecutar la sentencia la paso por el método bidnParam()

> Nota todo lo anterior probado desde XAMPP en mi laptop con PHP versión
>   7.2.1

Comment: Saludos @Alfredo Paz, y si tenia entendido que ambos pertenecen a mysqli, por eso tenia la duda si aun se podían usar o si fueron sustituidos como así lo es por los métodos que has dicho. Gracias por la aclaratoria!

Comment: Me temo que no tiene equivalencia `bind_result`  con el método `bind_param`  , el primero vincula las variables para almacenar **resultado** el otro es para agregar variables  a una sentencia preparada antes de ejecutarse.

Answer (score 1):

La respuesta es No , ya que estas funciones no son propias de la extensión `PDO`, más si lo son de `MySQLi` y tienen diferente fin.

[`bind_result`](http://php.net/manual/es/mysqli-stmt.bind-result.php) básicamente como su nombre lo indica es que vinculará una o más variables a una sentencia para almacenar resultados, estas están relacionadas al número de columnas que retornará su sentencia `SQL`, es decir una sentencia

```
SELECT nombre,edad from tabledatos where id=1
```

Necesitará que se vinculen dos variables para almacenar posibles resultados una para nombre y otra para edad , la sintaxis sería

```
$sentencia->bind_result($variablenombre, $variableedad);
/* obtenemos los valores  */
while ($sentencia->fetch()) {
    printf("%s %s\n", $variablenombre, $variableedad);
}
```

La función más cercana a esto , en `PDO` es [`fetchColumn`](http://php.net/manual/es/pdostatement.fetchcolumn.php)  que aceptará como parámetro el número de columna a obtener del resultado.

```
$sentencia= $pdo->prepare("SELECT nombre,edad from tabledatos where id=1");
$sentencia->execute();

//Obtener la segunda columna de los resultados
$resultado = $sentencia->fetchColumn(1); // obtenemos la edad
```

La función [`store_result`](http://php.net/manual/es/mysqli-stmt.store-result.php) simplemente se usa para almacenar el resultado de una sentencia en `buffer` , las sentencias posteriores como *(fetch)* obtendrían directamente los resultados del `buffer`, aunque a menudo se usa para comprobar si existen registros *(lo cuál no es tan correcto)* . También a menudo se usan las dos funciones juntas, para almacenar en `buffer` y para vincular variables de un resultado. Ejm

```
//almacenar en buffer
$stmt->store_result();      
if ($stmt->num_rows > 0) {

   //vincular a variables
   $stmt->bind_result($nombre,$edad);
   //Aquí estaríamos obteniendo los valores desde el buffer
   while ($stmt->fetch()){

   }
}
```

La función equivalente es el típico [`fetch`](http://php.net/manual/es/pdostatement.fetch.php) con el parámetro de acuerdo a lo que desea obtener y en que formato

```
$sentenciaPDO->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC); // Array Asociativo
```